# I have tried to make a request to the Endpoints using URL graphql in Hoppscotch but it returned a syntax error cannot parse the unexpected character

Tags: graphql, syntax-error, hoppscotch

Am a beginner at graphql and part of my assignment is to make a request to connect to the Endpoints so that I can access the data but its bringing an error. There's no much reading material on the Hoppscotch platform  on how to request data.

`query Request {`
`GET
https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=the+lord+of+the+rings

}`

the response;

`{ "errors": [ { "message": "Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character \"/\".", "locations": [ { "line": 3, "column": 8 } ] } ] }`